# How do I use for loop in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to update multiple rows(29) in a table in SQL server 2005.

```
SELECT * from tblState ORDER BY StateCode ASC.
```

In this table there's a integer column which I need to assign numbers starting from 1 to 29. For e.g.

```
BEFORE

A 3 

B 6

C 2 
D 1
```

```
AFTER

A 1  
B 2  
C 3  
D 4
```

How can I update each row with a ascending sequential number efficiently?

Comment: If you need to ask, you are doing it wrong. You should be using set operations and try to never loop in SQL.

Comment: how do you know which rows need to be updated? Are you trying to create your own index?

Comment: I need to update all the rows in the table.
There are two columns in this table, one is varchar in which all the statelist is having different state name codes. 
The other column is integer which 'll have sorting order. 
I need to sort the first column alphabetically and assing ranks to them and update that particula table

Comment: @UserM - Both the answers below do exactly that.

Comment: Why do you want to store this number in the table? You are just creating a maintenance problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH
  sequenced_data AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StateCode ASC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    tblState
)
UPDATE
  sequenced_data
SET
  integer_column = sequence_id
```

As you are asking for a loop I guess you may not understand this code.

As such, I strongly recommend you create a dummy table to play with this, both to understand that how it works, and to ensure it does what you want/expect.

- The `WITH` statement is similar to a sub query
- In that, the `ROW_NUMBER()` creates the sequential ids that you want
- The outer query then updates the column *(Although it refers to the sub-query, the real table does actually get updated)*

Comment: nice job +1. I like how you update direcly cte table. Checked and running: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82094

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked and yes I didn't understand the code first time..  +1

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid loops in SQL whenever possible. SQL Server is heavily optimized towards set-based operations.

In this case you can use a `CTE` with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.90).aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT StateCode, IntColumn
   ,  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StateCode ASC)
   FROM dbo.tblState
)
UPDATE CTE SET IntColumn = RN;
```

[Bad Habits to Kick : Thinking a WHILE loop isn't a CURSOR](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor)

Comment: I think you should put that link back in, I for one think it is useful to people who want to write loops in SQL :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with CTE1 as(select StateCode,intcol,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by StateCode) as rn from tbln)
update CTE1 set intcol=rn
select * from tbln
```

Comment: Errr, the OP is asking how to create the ids ordered by StateCode.  And in this code only one of your two CTEs is actually used.

Comment: Umm, yes the OP did.  The OP has `ORDER BY SateCode ASC` in the first piece of code.  Then has before and after examples of the data.  And added a comment to the question reiterating that requirement.

Comment: yeah sorry I did not check that

Answer (score 0):

You can use Common Table Expressions

```
with c as
(
    select ID, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (order by StateCode ASC) as cn 
    from tblState 
)
update c set ID = cn
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, don't store the number in the table because you will have to change it every time you insert a new row.

Just do

```
SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StateCode ASC) sequence_id
              , *   
    FROM 
              tblState
```

every time you get the data out.

If you have many rows and you need to do this fast, create an index on `StateCode ASC`

Answer (score 0):

My option without cte:

```
UPDATE d
SET d.integer_column = d.sequence_id
FROM (
      SELECT integer_column, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StateCode ASC) AS sequence_id 
      FROM dbo.tblState
      ) d
```